# converting angular dynamic table to angular2 reactive form

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to convert [a working example of an angular dynamic table](https://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/yxdvu10x/) into an angular2 reactive form. I want to achieve the same functionality in an angular 2 form:

- submit 3 new input values which get added to a table
- new values and also get added to the formArray each time

I think I’m close but I think there must be something in how I’m writing the initData function that is making it fail. Am I right in thinking I can pass the new Data entry as an argument of initData function in order to update the formArray?

Any help or direction appreciated!
thanks

[live Plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2CRs2DdUCSD01yl4q5yt?p=preview)

**app.component.html**

```
  <div formArrayName="personalDetails ">
  <input [(ngModel)]="newData.fname" type="text" formControlName="fname">
  <input [(ngModel)]="newData.lname" type="text" formControlName="lname">
  <input [(ngModel)]="newData.email" type="text" formControlName="email">
  </div>
  <button (click)=addNew()>Add</button>

  <table >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let personalDetail of myForm.controls.personalDetails.controls" >
         <td>{{personalDetail.fname}}</td>
         <td>{{personalDetail.lname}}</td>
         <td>{{personalDetail.email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
        export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
         public myForm: FormGroup;
         public newData: Data;

            constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

            ngOnInit() {
                this.newData = new Data();

                this.myForm = this._fb.group({
                    personalDetails : this._fb.array([
                        this.initData(entryObj),
                    ])
                });
            }

            // create the new formGroup to push to the personalDetails array
            initData(entryObj:any) {
                return this._fb.group({
                    fname: [entryObj.fname],
                    lname: [entryObj.lname],
                    email: [entryObj.email]
                });
            }

            // add new set of Data
            // the new entry variable will be the argument for initData
            addNew() {
                if (this.newData) {
                    var entry = {
                        'fname': this.newData.fname,
                        'lname': this.newData.lname,
                        'email': this.newData.email
                    };

                    // add to the form controls
                    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['personalDetails '];
                    control.push(this.initData(entry));
                }
            }
        } 
    export class Data {
      public fname: string;
      public lname: string;
      public email: string;
}
```

In terms of approach I’ve tried to take reference from [the scotch example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sUjE1ULYhfDHLNBw2sRv?p=preview), the major difference being the requirement here is that new formGroup values are submitted at the same time as augmenting the form array.